# Python, Postgres - SQL query where clause with string = Curaçao

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am on Windows 8 environment using Python 2.7, psycopg2 and Postgres.

Postgres database has following encoding:

```
Encoding    UTF8
Collation   English_United States.1252
Character Type  English_United States.1252
Tablespace  pg_default
```

I have inserted records into this database that have filenames based on country names, values such as:

```
cuba.png
curaçao.png
cyprus.png
czech_republic.png
côte_d'ivoire.png
democratic_republic_of_congo.png
```

I have files in a folder that have corresponding names:

```
cuba.png
curaçao.png
cyprus.png
czech_republic.png
côte_d'ivoire.png
democratic_republic_of_congo.png
```

I am using this code to loop through files and then write file details back to database using UPDATE with a WHERE clause that compares the database record file name to the actual file's name.

```
import os, os.path
from PIL import Image
import psycopg2

conn_string = \
    "host='localhost' \
    dbname='dbname' \
    user='username' \
    password='password'" 

conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)     
cur = conn.cursor()
print conn.encoding

screenshots_path = 'C:/path/to/screenshots/'

screenshots_dir = os.listdir(screenshots_path)
for file in screenshots_dir:
    if file != 'Thumbs.db':
        img = Image.open(screenshots_path + file)
        img256 = img.convert('P', palette=Image.ADAPTIVE, colors=5)
        colors = img256.getcolors()
        color_str = ','.join(str(v) for v in colors)

        cur.execute("UPDATE screenshots \
        set color_palette = %s \
        WHERE filename like %s", \
        (color_str, '%' + 'screenshots/' + file + '%',))
        conn.commit()

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

However when it gets to curaçao (or any other country with accents etc) it gives following error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_color.py", line 39, in <module>
    cur.execute("UPDATE screenshots set color_palette = %s WHERE filename like %
s", (color_str, '%' + 'screenshots/' + file + '%',))
psycopg2.DataError: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xe7 0x61 0x6f
```

The actual file's name as retrieved and printed is:

```
curaτao.png
```

System encoding:

```
import sys
print sys.getdefaultencoding()
returns ascii
```

Database encoding confirmed:

```
print conn.encoding
returns UTF8
```

I believe I need to get the file name into same format/encoding as the database file name so they two strings can be compared.

I am doing my head in trying to work out how to get equivalency so the WHERE clause can be used.

I have trawled over scores of other SO questions and web pages and am just not clear what needs to be done.

I have tried resetting default encoding

```
import sys
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('Cp1252')  (with 'latin1', Cp1252, etc)
```

I removed data from database as csv and then recreated database with UTF-8 encoding and reimported csv data.

I have tried to append u' to file name before using .encode('utf-8').

What am I missing?

Comment: your utf is getting trashed, which means that SOME stage of your pipeline is using a different character set, and is trashing the multibyte sequences.

Comment: Ok. I checked original csv source of country names. It had ascii encoding and I imported it into utf-8 encoded Postgres db. Assumed Postgres would encode csv as utf-8 but it doesn't.